# Why does Boost Variant use the template constructor instead of the move constructor for boost::beast::websocket::stream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, boost-beast

I am trying to wrap `boost::beast::websocket::stream<T>` (for 2 specific `T`) in a `boost::variant` to allow treating TLS (`[T = boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>]`) and non-TLS (`[T = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket]`) websockets the same. I am stuck at a compilation failure.

The simplest failing example that I can come up with is:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ws = boost::beast::websocket;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;

using base_ws = boost::variant<
    ws::stream<tcp::socket>, ws::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>>>;

class test
{
 public:
    static void init( tcp::socket &&  socket )
    {
        ssl::context  ctx{ ssl::context::tlsv12_server };
        ws::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>>  s{ std::move( socket ), ctx };
        base_ws{ std::move( s ) };
    }
};

int main()
{}
```

Which fails to compile with error:

```
In file included from /server/src/ws_server.cpp:9:
In file included from /include/boost/beast/websocket.hpp:18:
In file included from /include/boost/beast/websocket/stream.hpp:3455:
/include/boost/beast/websocket/impl/stream.ipp:47:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >'
    : stream_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
      ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:122:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >::stream<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >' requested here
                new(dest) value_T( boost::detail::variant::move(operand) );
                          ^
/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1687:28: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<1> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > >::initializer_node::initialize' requested here
              initializer::initialize(
                           ^
/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1858:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >::convert_construct<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >' requested here
        convert_construct( detail::variant::move(operand), 1L);
        ^
/server/src/ws_server.cpp:372:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >::variant<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >' requested here
            return base_ws( std::move( s ) );
                   ^
/include/boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp:64:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >' to 'const boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >' for 1st argument
class stream :
      ^
/include/boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp:98:3: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  stream(Arg&& arg, context& ctx)
  ^
```

I would provide godbolt however it times out, and coliru does not provide openssl which is required for `boost/asio/ssl.hpp`.

Per [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#id-1_3_46_5_4_1_1_11-bb), `boost::variant` should accept `T &&` and use it to instantiate `T` internally.

Per [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/stream/overload1.html), `boost::beast::websocket::stream` does have a move constructor.

The move constructor is more specific, so why is the compiler selecting the variadic constructor (`stream<...>`) as indicated in the first note?

```
boost::beast::websocket::stream<
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<
    boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>
  >
>::stream<
  boost::beast::websocket::stream<
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<
      boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>
    >
  >
>
```

I am using Boost 1.66.0 and Clang 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical information I overlooked was in the description of `boost::beast::websocket::stream::stream(stream&&)`:

> **If `NextLayer` is move constructible**, this function will move-construct a new stream from the existing stream.

It turns out that `boost::asio::ssl::stream` is not move constructible, so the defaulted move constructor of `stream` was not generated. There is an open issue to make `ssl::stream` move constructible in [chriskohlhoff/asio#124](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/124) which references the [boost bugtracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9724).

A solution to the problem then is to use a move constructible implementation of `ssl::stream`, like the one provided in the Beast examples [here](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/d52e8290453fe445c8700b4819fe8e4f45633a02/example/common/ssl_stream.hpp), which looks like it may be available at `boost/beast/experimental/core/ssl_stream.hpp` in a later version of Beast (not in 1.67.0).

Answer (score 0):

The **advanced-server-flex** example shows how to build a server with code that handles both SSL and plain websocket sessions, without the need to resort to a variant: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/c2ecba968c06a22a61c67b8887f5b477bb32a99a/example/advanced/server-flex/advanced_server_flex.cpp#L227

Comment: Thank you, I did review the flex server code. In my case I am providing a pimpl class and wanted to avoid the interface and impl from being templated, so I have the variant as a member of the implementation. If not for that I would go with your approach since 1. the websocket interface loses no flexibility and 2. no runtime penalty. To provide the functions I inherit from https://gist.github.com/chrahunt/e738c890a1655c3c18cd27bdf360fd43#file-etc-cpp then use like `async_read( ws_, buffer_, etc... )` which doesn't feel so bad to write but I still need to profile.